# In an ordered field, must 1 be positive?

Tags: field-theory

In an ordered field, must the multiplicative identity be positive? Or must it be defined as such?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remember that for a total order,

1. If $a \leq b$, then $a+c \leq b+c$.
2. If $0 \leq a$ and $0 \leq b$, then $0 \leq ab$.

If $1 \leq 0$, then $1+(-1) \leq 0 + (-1)$ i.e. $0 \leq -1$. By ($2$), we need $0 \leq (-1)(-1) = 1$.

Hence, we get that $1 \leq 0 \leq 1$. For a non-trivial field, $0 \neq 1$. Hence, we get a contradiction that $$1 < 0 < 1.$$

Hence, $0 < 1$.

Comment: Minor point - $0 = 1$ is excluded by definition of field.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka Well true. But some people call it a trivial field when $0=1$, while others tend to include $0 \neq 1$ in the definition of the field. So it depends...

Comment: Thanks, Marvis. I have written a formal version of your proof. See Lemma 8 beginning at line 312 in http://www.dcproof.com/FieldLemmas.htm

Comment: @DanChristensen Interesting website. I assume it would have involved a lot of work! Good luck!

Comment: Actually, your definition of a total order is incorrect. A total order is merely a partial order that is strongly connected, by definition. That the ring operator $+$ is bi-monotonic is not implied by the definition of a total order, but rather, it is a consequence of how an additive order is defined on a ring. In fact, in an arbitrary ordered field, it is impossible to distinguish a priori a total order from its converse order via the axioms alone. The only way to uniquely specify the order is to specify that $0\lt1$ or $0\gt1,$ one way or the other.

Answer (score 6):

$1$ cannot be negative because its sign is also that of $1\cdot 1$, and negative times negative must make positive. Since also $1\ne 0$, it must be positive.